# print using process.stdout.write but come with nowhere letter 'D'

Tags: javascript, process, console.log

I try to read the input and transfer to two number N and K, and array of number votes as parameters pass to function, and return array of number. And print the each element of array on each line. But when I print out the each element, the first integer come with nowhere letter 'D'. Here is the terminal looks like. First two line is that input and using ctrl + D to determine and get array [3, 0, -2].

Please help me to figure out this letter 'D'. Thank you everyone.

> ```
> 5 3
> 1 2 3 1 1
> 3D
> 0
> -2
> ```

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
let line1 = ""
let line2 = ""
process.stdin.on("data", function(data) {
  if (line1 != "" && line2 == "") {
    line2 += data
  } else if (line1 == "") {
    line1 += data
  }
})
process.stdin.on("end", function() {
  let N = line1.split(' ').map(Number)[0];
  let K = line1.split(' ').map(Number)[1];
  let votes = line2.split(' ').map(Number);
  processData(N, K, votes);
})

function processData(N, K, votes) {
  // call upvotesAnalyze function, it will return an array
  // like [3, 0, -2]
  let results = upvotesAnalyze(votes, N, K);
  results.forEach(e => {
     // or I have tried 
     // process.stdout.write(e);
    console.log(e);
  })
}
```

Comment: it looks like `upvotesAnalyze` function is returning the D. Can you share the code of `upvotesAnalyze`?